# jQuery appending multiple cloned DOM objects using a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm attempting to make a simple shopping cart that pulls in cart objects from another page using a JSON file. However when I begin the process of appending a cloned DOM object to the product-list div it only appends the last object in the loop, essentially overwriting any objects before the final iteration.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var cartArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
    console.log(cartArray);
    parseData(cartArray);
})

    function parseData(item){

        // grab a clone of the aside
        $copy = $('.cart-selection').clone();

        //loop through and append a clone with modified JSON information for each item in the cart array
        for(i=0; i<item.length; i++){
            console.log(i);
            $('h2', $copy).html(item[i].name);
            $('img', $copy).attr("src", item[i].url);
            $copy.appendTo($('product-list'));
        }           
    }
```

I've tried several different variations using both .append and .appendTo with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can we see your json

Comment: you must create the $copy inside the loop

Comment: that's true. $copy should be inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create another copy of the clone inside the loop.
The idea is to create a "prototype" of the element, and then create a copy of that prototype for each item in your loop:

```
    // grab a clone of the aside
    $clone= $('.cart-selection').clone();

    //loop through and append a clone with modified JSON information for each item in the cart array
    for(i=0; i<item.length; i++){

        // create a copy of the clone
        $copy = $clone.clone();  

        console.log(i);
        $('h2', $copy).html(item[i].name);
        $('img', $copy).attr("src", item[i].url);
        $copy.appendTo($('product-list'));
    }
```

Comment: After placing $copy inside the loop it now exponentially generates the DOM element I've cloned. Eg. for an array of 3 items it generates 7 copies of the DOM.

Comment: I have editted my answer. Please check if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess product-list is a class name or ID something?

```
$copy.appendTo($('product-list')); <--
```

if so, you may need to use **.product-list** or **#product-list**

Comment: You are correct, it was a class name. Missed that one. Thanks! @Dr.Molle I put $copy in the loop and now it exponentially generates the cloned DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the clone in the loop else you will be creating only one clone of the target element and you are just changing its content in the loop

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    var cartArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
    console.log(cartArray);
    parseData(cartArray);
})

function parseData(item) {
    //loop through and append a clone with modified JSON information for each item in the cart array
    for (i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {

        // grab a clone of the aside, need to do in the loop because for each item in the loop we need a new element
        //also should clone only the first instance of the cart-selection else in each iteration you will get multiple elements
        var $copy = $('.cart-selection').eq(0).clone();

        console.log(i);
        $('h2', $copy).html(item[i].name);
        $('img', $copy).attr("src", item[i].url);
        //need to fix the selector here, may be you need a class selector if product-list is a class
        $copy.appendTo($('.product-list'));
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d4x871sj/)

Comment: This was also really helpful. Wish I could put a check next to both answers I received. Thanks!